# PyGtk gi show image using cv2 in image widget

Tags: python, pygtk, pygobject

I tried this code to display images in a PyGtk image widget. But it shows blank lines.

```
img_gtk = Gtk.Image()
# Do other things such as attaching the 'img_gtk' to a window/grid...

# Convert and display:
h, w, d = img.shape
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data  (img.tostring(), GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, w, h, w*3, None, None)
img_gtk.set_from_pixbuf (pixbuf)
```

How can i do this using pixbuf?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is memory management - by the time Gtk.Image wants to display the image, the content of pixbuf is gone. Simply make a copy with:
`img_gtk.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf.copy())`